# Find ratios in a paralleogram using Thales's theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, $Q$ lies on $AC$ such that $AQ:QC=1:3$. $DQ$ intersects $AB$ and $BC$ in $M$ and $P$, respectively. I should find $AM:MB$, $BC:PC$ and $DM:QP$.
>   [image]

We **have NOT** studied similar triangles, and I should solve the problem by using Thales's theorem. Which angle should we look at for the first ratio? What about $\angle AQD$?
[image]
I guess in this problem $\triangle AMQ \sim \triangle DQC$, but I cannot use this.

Comment: THALES theorem does not require that the two parallels are on the same side of the angle. Do you can use THALES for $AMQDC$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thales theorem tells us that

$${DC\over AM}={QC\over AQ}=3$$

Because $CD=AB=AM+MB$ we have

$${MB\over AM}=2$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Which angle are we looking at?

Comment: The angle in $Q$ precisely $\hat{DQC}=\hat{MQA}$

Comment: I haven't seen the case when the two parallels are not on the same side of the angle. Where can I read about it because I am not sure I can always see and write the correct ratios because as I said we have not studied similar triangles.

Comment: You can see it easily starting with the case you and taking a reflection relative to the vertex of the angle of the largest triangle